# Home page in Site Map

Tags: seo, sitemap

Just a question about Site Map. In your site  you record the home page like [www.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr](http://www.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr)
Behind, the root, you have a page like: Accueil-Informatique-Limoges.aspx
but in sitemap, Is it good to indexed the home page like?

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr/Accueil-Informatique-Limoges.aspx</loc>
<lastmod>2014-08-18</lastmod>
<priority>1.0</priority>
<changefreq>yearly</changefreq>
</url>
```

Or Is it stupid. Cause When I search in Goole

> site:YannickIngenierie-informatique.fr

I don't see my homePage (http://www.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr/Accueil-Informatique-Limoges.aspx), but only the root (http://www.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *home page* is '*www.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr*', while the '*http://www.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr/Accueil-Informatique-Limoges.aspx*' is just a regular *1st-level page*. It's a good idea to have them both in the *XML sitemap* (of course, if you'd like both of them to be indexed by a SE).

Comment: I don't have the root in my SiteMap. For you it's better to write it? And Why when I search Site:Mysite The HomePage in aspx is not here?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what do you mean.

Comment: In my SiteMap file I write only _XXX.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr/Accueil-Informatique-Limoges.aspx_ but not _XXX.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr_ And when you search on Google **Site:yannickingenierie-informatique.fr**  You see _XXX.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr_ but not _XXX.yannickingenierie-informatique.fr/Accueil-Informatique-Limoges.aspx_ Why?

Comment: It's Google. It indexes only what he thinks should be indexed.